# Mvc6 trim all values of json model before validation (incl. strings in nested model objects)

Tags: validation, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using Mvc6 beta6 and model is passed in Json format. What is the recommended way to trim all values inside json model before it is validated? I also need to trim values of strings of nested objects inside the model.

Here is an example:

```
[HttpPut("{userId}/{id}/details")]    
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateProfileDetails(string userId, string id, [FromBody] UserProfileDetailsModel userProfileDetailsModel)
{
  // Inside the action all (nested)values of userProfileDetailsModel should be already trimmed without the need to trim them manually based on model type
}
```

So provided userProfileDetailsModel has a nested object "geoLocation" : { "continent" : "   EU "} the effect I'm trying to obtain is having the continent value trimmed as "EU" when reading this value inside the action.

I'm looking for a global filter or global formatter solution which does not depend on model type.

Comment: did you find a way to trim all values?

Answer (score 1):

Try creating your own model binder
[Simple ModelBinder](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/ModelBinding/SimpleTypeModelBinder.cs)

There's a sample available as well at:
[Model Binding Sample WebSite](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/tree/229724c4eab3bf4fc8390deca9af7e451e5caee7/test/WebSites/ModelBindingWebSite)

You are using [FromBody] which I believe uses input formatters and prevents model binders from running, in that case if you want to go more on the formatter route, have a look at [Formatter Sample Web Site](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/tree/229724c4eab3bf4fc8390deca9af7e451e5caee7/test/WebSites/FormatterWebSite)